# Not understanding the match function of a HashMap.entry()

Tags: rust

I am just starting to learn Rust. The entry method an Entry enum, which can be accessed via the match function. But then I don't get why it doesn't compile and it panics.
Can someone explain please what I'm understanding wrong?

```
let mut scores: HashMap<String, u32> = HashMap::new();

scores.insert(String::from("Blue"), 10);
scores.insert(String::from("Yellow"), 50);

let a = 10;
match scores.entry("poneyland".to_string()) {
    Occupied(o) => o.remove_entry(),
    Vacant(o) =>  o.insert(37),
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? I've tried to compile your code (after adding necessary imports) and got the "incompatible types" error which is not tied to `entry` API specifically, is this what you're asking about?

Comment: Please build a proper [mre], which should include _all_ the code required to reproduce the problem that you are facing, and ideally the compiler's error message.

Comment: _"which can be accessed by the match function_" it is a _match expression_, but remember that each match arm needs to ultimately evaluate to the same type, as already hinted above. _"it doesn't compile and it panics"_ not compiling and panicking are two very different mechanisms, so please take care when reporting what happened. It is considered a bug when the compiler itself panics (that would be an internal compiler error, also known as ICE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But then I don't get why it doesn't compile and it panics.

It can't both fail to compile and panic, since panic is a runtime behaviour. Either way, when there is an error it is usually a good idea to post it, as that makes diagnostic much easier, especially in Rust which generally has pretty helpful error messages.

In this case, the compilation error tells you exactly what's what:

```
error[E0308]: `match` arms have incompatible types
  --> src/main.rs:15:22
   |
13 | /     match scores.entry("poneyland".to_string()) {
14 | |         Occupied(o) => o.remove_entry(),
   | |                        ---------------- this is found to be of type `(String, u32)`
15 | |         Vacant(o) => o.insert(37),
   | |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected tuple, found `&mut u32`
16 | |     }
   | |_____- `match` arms have incompatible types
   |
   = note:          expected tuple `(String, u32)`
           found mutable reference `&mut u32`
```

You pretty much just need to read the message, [and possibly the expanded document](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0308).

What it boils down to is a rust `match` is an *expression*, meaning it has a value of a specific type, meaning *all arms must have values of the same type* (or a compatible type e.g. `!`).

Here, as the compiler error tells you, in one arm you're calling [`remove_entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.OccupiedEntry.html#method.remove_entry) which returns a tuple of (key, value), while in the other arm you're calling [`insert`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.VacantEntry.html#method.insert) which returns a mutable reference to the inserted value.

These types are obviously not compatible.

The easiest way to fix this is to make them compatible by... suppressing the results entirely since you're not using them: convert the arm expressions to arm [blocks](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/block-expr.html) and terminate the expressions with `;`. That makes the expressions into statements and suppresses their value, implicitly returning `()` instead:

```rust
    match scores.entry("poneyland".to_string()) {
        Occupied(o) => {
            o.remove_entry();
        }
        Vacant(o) => {
            o.insert(37);
        }
    }
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1b885daa2a4eaa6d9d7c366753f6c2aa

Comment: Thank you, everything is clear now, I wasnt aware that without ; are interpreted as returns.

Comment: They're not "interpreted as returns", it's just the result of the expression, like the expression `1` results in the value `1`.